# Implement a Verilog $onehot task in Chisel

Tags: scala, one-hot-encoding, chisel

Is there a straightforward way to check a 1-hot bus encoding in Chisel?

My current solution seems a bit ugly. Can I do better?

```
val range = Output (Vec (num, Bool()))
val outSum = io.range map ( p => if ( p == true.B ) 1.U else 0.U ) reduceleft (_ + _)

// This is $onehot0
assert (outSum <= 1.U, "One-hot0 bus encoding failed")

// This is $onehot
assert (outSum == 1.U, "One-hot bus encoding failed")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [PopCount](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/chisel3/util/PopCount$.html)

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util.PopCount

...

val io = IO(new Bundle {
  val range = Output(Vec(num, Bool()))
})
val outSum = PopCount(io.range)
// assertions...
```